# There are two pandas tables, each containing two columns. I need to create a third table based on the 2 tables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There are two pandas tables, each containing two columns. In the first, it's time and heart rate. The second is the time and systolic pressure.
I need to write code that creates a third table, which for each pressure measurement in the same row contains the time and value of the nearest heart rate measurement, if it was made necessarily before the pressure measurement and not earlier than 15 minutes.
[image: DataFrames]

Third DF must be something like this:
[image]

I have tried join/megre/concat with different conditions but don't get what i need.

Comment: Can you provide the DataFrame constructors of your two inputs?

Comment: Please provide the DataFrames as code and not as images.